# Calculate second derivative using unknown, evaluatable function and it's unknown, evaluatable first derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose we have an **unknown**, continuous and infinitely differentiable function $f(x)$ and it's first derivative $df/dx$ (also unknown). Both f and df can be evaluated, but are unknown equation-wise.

Is it possible to calculate it's second derivative using only this information? Both exact solutions and approximations are welcome.

Comment: Do you mean that we can evaluate $f$ and $f'$ at $a$, say, and we want $f''(a)$?

Comment: Yes indeed! That's it

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can! As long as you know it is continuous and infinitely differentiable.

If you know how to calculate $df/dx$ when given $f(x)$, then it is the exact same as calculating $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$ given $df/dx$.

To give a physical example, if you are given the equation of velocity of a projectile, you can find its equation of acceleration by taking the derivative of the velocity equation, which is the derivative of the displacement equation.

Comment: f and df are unknown, so that's not an option I'm afraid

Comment: So you're saying both are unknown? If so then you should probably change the title as it is a little misleading.

Comment: They are unknown equation-wise, but I can still evaluate both d and df. So symbolic differentiation is not possible, but maybe an approximation was